# nginx expires doesn't work

Tags: nginx

Here's the relevant nginx configuration fragment:

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    expires max;
    rewrite ^/static/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 last;
}
```

After reloading nginx there's no sign of the Expires header for some reason:

```
$ curl -i http://monda.hu/static/1/blog/wp-content/icomoon/style.css

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2013 22:55:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 1783
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 21:03:00 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "51e5b504-6f7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

(The idea here is to increment the numeric version value in the URL whenever the related resource changes.  Please do not tell me that `expires max` is a bad practice.  I think it's a matter of taste and priorities.)

Other than the above there are the following location blocks present in the relevant server section:

```
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
location / { ... }
location ~ /\. { ... }
location ^~ /mydbadmin/ { ... }
location @php { ... }  # this one is not even referenced
```

Comment: What's in the location block that the request gets re-written to?

Comment: Just added the header of the other location blocks that are present in the relevant server section.  I think that none of these should interfere with the static block.